# What does "array.length -1" mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I know how to use the JavaScript for loops to cycle through arrays for example, but I still didn't understand what the `array.length -1` means, specifically the `-1` part.

When using a for loop over an array we have something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {...}
```

But I've seen also something like this, sometimes:

```
for (i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {...}
```

In the second case, why there is the "-1" in the array.length and what does it do? Also why sometimes there is and sometimes isn't it shown?

Comment: Since javascript is zero-indexed , in order to loop through an entire array, you can either set the maximum bound as i<array.length OR i<=array.length-1

Comment: Well, in the second case, you added an off-by-one error =D

Answer (score 23):

It's to prevent fencepost errors, aka "off-by-one".

Common exam question:

> You are required build 100 meters of fence, with a fence post every meter. How many fenceposts will you need?

Obvious quick (and WRONG) answer:

```
    100 meters
  --------------- = 100 posts
     1 post
     ------
     meter
```

Because for 100 meters of fence, you need 101 posts:

```
Distance:    1 2  ....  99 100
            |-|-|.....| - | - |
Post:       1 2 3 ....99  100 101
```

Now with arrays, the same thing happens. Let's say it's an array with 5 items:

```
for (i = 0 ; i <= 5; i++)
                  ^--length of array
```

You end up doing

```
        i:    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
iteration:    1  2  3  4  5  6
```

Oops. 5 item array, but you've executed your loop 6 times - one times too many.

You can fix the error in two ways:

```
for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
              ^---change from "<=" to "<"
```

or

```
for (i = 0; i <= length - 1; i++)
                        ^---change the upper limit value.
```

Comment: First of all, thanks Marc for your fast and completed answer. Just a thing: in your for loop you've put in the second condition i <= 5. That gives you the i of 0,1,2,3,4,5 and the iteration of 1,2,3,4,5,6. Why didn't you write directly i < 5?

Comment: `i < length` and `i <= length - 1` are equivalent

Comment: remember that `for` keeps going until that check condition goes false, so... `i<=5` will be TRUE for i=5 (array element #6). if you switch to `i<5`, then when `i` becomes 5, `i<5` becomes `false` and the loop aborts. for integers, `i<5` and `i<=4` (aka `i<=5-1`) are effectively identical

Comment: choosing which to use is entirely up to the programmer. Personally, I'll with the `<= count minus 1` variation, since it makes it clear that you're stopping at one below the count. `< count` is easy to misinterpret. but that's purely a stylistic choice, and therefore opinion, and therefore off-topic.

Answer (score 4):

If your array has 4 elements, for example

```
var elementOfArray = [7, 9, 0, 2]
```

and you want to reach those elements. In that case, you need to know that `elementOfArray[i]` represents element of your array and **i is the index**.

For that reason, **if you add '-1' on your array length**; you can see whole elements in your array like `elementOfArray[0]---7`, `elementOfArray[1]---9`, `elementOfArray[2]---0`, `elementOfArray[3]---2`. See! you took the whole number in the element.

**If you do not subtract 1 of array length**, you would take an error. Because there is no `elementOfArray[4]` that represents any element of your array.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript arrays are 0-based, meaning if you have an array of 5 items, you would use the indices 0 through 4 to access them. They're subtracting one (there should be a space between '-' and '1' to make it more clear) to find the last index.

Edited: If they're subtracting one, the test should be '<='.

Answer (score 0):

If you access multiple indices at once you generally want to avoid a overflow by making sure every accessed index is `< array.length`

so if you do something like this

```
array[x+2] = array[x] + array[x+1];
```

you generally want to make sure that the highest occuring value in the `[]` is lower than array.length

then your for in the upper example would probably look like

```
for(int x = 0; x+2 < array.length; x++) {
   array[x+2] = array[x] + array[x+1];
}
```

which is the mathematically equlivalent to

```
for(int x = 0; x < array.length - 2; x++) {
   array[x+2] = array[x] + array[x+1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I found after some research and experiment. The items in your list start to count from 1, that's obvious, but the index starts to count from "0". So, let's say you're looping through your array/list and you state the length of the whole array. for example: let array = [1,2,3,4];
for (i = 0; i <= array.length; i++){
alert(i)
}
The last alert is going to show "undefined" because the array has no item that has the index of 4 (though the items in the array are). so the a good practice would be "i < array.length" or "i <= array.length - 1". Please correct me if I'm missing something, or if you need more clarification.