# Can somebody explain why -1 is used in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, slider

I am watching a javascript tutorial to create testimonial slider.in this javascript project i didn't understand why they use "slides.length-1".Why cant we give only slide.length only.why -1 should be included in the code can anybody explain?

```js
const next = document.querySelector('.next');
const prev = document.querySelector('.prev');
const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');

let index = 0;
display(index);
function display (index) {
    slides.forEach((slide) => {
        slide.style.display = 'none';
    });
    slides[index].style.display = 'flex';
}

function nextSlide () {
    index++;
    if (index > slides.length - 1) {
        index = 0;
    }
    display(index);
}
function prevSlide () {
    index--;
    if (index < 0) {
        index = slides.length - 1;
    }
    display(index);
}

next.addEventListener('click', nextSlide);
prev.addEventListener('click', prevSlide);
```

Comment: because arrays are 0-indexed

Comment: `index` starts from 0. `.length` start from 1. The -1 puts them on the same scale

Comment: Because first element of an Arrays is 0, so you need to remove 1 if you're working with the length

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "array.length -1" mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35024593/what-does-array-length-1-mean-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is all because we count indexes from 0**

Imagine having an array of length 5. **This means that array has 5 elements**.

But their indexes are: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 (five elements in total).

That's why when you want to access last element of any array you use:

```
myArray[myArray.length - 1]
```

which is literally `myArray[5 - 1]` so `myArray[4]`. And as I mentioned, indexes in array of length 5 are: **0**, **1**, **2**, **3** and last but not least: **4**

Answer (score 0):

Because the numbering in JS going from 0. If you have array with 5 strings - length = 5. when we want to iterate an array we start from 0. Example:
var test = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];

// test.length = 5;
// but '1' is on 0 position. '2' on 1, '3' on 2d position, '4' on 3, and '5' on 4th postion. If index not - 1, he will search for 5th element, but we don't have it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).